# Find the generator of a markov process with constant decay and exponential jumps

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Suppose we have a continuous time Markov process $(X_t)_{t\in [0,\infty)}$. This Markov process represents the queue length in amount of work left, therefore its state space is given as $S = [0,\infty)$.

Arrivals occur according to a state-dependent $\mbox{Poisson}(\lambda(s))$ and when an arrival occurs, the state increases by an exponential random variable with mean $1$.

Meanwhile the value of $X_t$ also decreases at a constant speed of $1$, thus if no arrivals occur, $X_{t+s} = (X_t - s) \vee 0$.

How do I find the [generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal_generator_(stochastic_processes)) which corresponds to this process? In parti

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, $X_t$ is a **piecewise deterministic process** with generator  $L f(x) = -I_{\{ x>0 \}} f'(x) + \lambda(x)^{-1} \mathbb{E} \{ f(x+t) - f(x) \}$ where the expected value is over the exponential random variable $t$ with parameter $1$.

Comment: As a reference on PDPs, look no further than: Davis, M. H. A. *Markov Models & Optimization*. Vol. 49. CRC Press, 1993.

Comment: Thank you, already a very good response, but I would like to add a possible complication (I would just like to hear your thoughts):
Actually the arrival process $\mbox{Poisson}(\lambda(s))$ depends on the stationary distribution of the process itself. My plan is: Find the stationary distribution by taking a deterministic approximation of the process (which I already did) and then use this deterministic approximation as the stationary distribution.
The background is: It is actually a Density Dependent Population Process as in the Kurtz book Characterizaton and Convergence of Markov Processes.

Comment: But in this book only discrete state spaces are considered.

Comment: Concerning "Actually the arrival process ...", what do you mean by **deterministic approximation of the process**?

Comment: 1. I mean the Density Dependent Population Processes considered in this book: https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Markov+Processes%3A+Characterization+and+Convergence-p-9780471769866 
These are only considered for discrete state space.
2. I have an approximation by the method introduced here: (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/B:QUES.0000027998.95375.ee)
It gives me a deterministic integral equation which my function needs to satisfy, I can solve this equation exactly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70834/discussion-between-nawaf-bou-rabee-and-holymonk).

Comment: What did you want to say in your last sentence?